# How to unify the color of graduated classes (in symbology) across several maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

I have got 3 maps for the same parameter across several years.
I want the color of each class (e.g. 0.801-1.000) across all three maps to be the same to make comparison easily. This can be done manually by changing the color.

Is there any way to do it faster?

[image]

Comment: This can certainly be accomplished using `ArcObjects`. Are you looking for a solution involving programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it once for one map.  Then, you simply right click on the layer and "Save as Layer File."

[image]

In the other maps, go to the symbology tab on the layer you want to change.  Click the Import... button.

[image]

Import the symbology from the saved layer file.

[image]

Comment: +1 Looks like we answered within a minute/seconds of each other :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a layer file for one of the datasets with the desired class breaks, colors for each break, and labeling. Then apply that layer file as the symbology for each dataset/year.